regex in grep vs sed
I am trying to find and replace all lines in a text file that start with a single space and then any characters.
Finally got the regex to work on grep grep -E '^ .*$*' Contacts.vcf >> t.txt
Then when using it on sed it does not sed 's/^ .*$//g' Contacts.vcf > tt.txt - I get all lines (regardless if have a blank space at the start). I have tried \s{1} and putting everything in () but cannot get it to work.
I encountered the same issue when trying it on Windows with PowerShell at first. I feel I am missing the minutiae of the Regex between platforms(?).
How do I force a regex to only find lines that start with a single space?

You can simplify the grep by realising the "begin with space followed by any character
grep '^ .'

If you just want "begins with space" then it's even easier
grep '^ '

Now the sed, it changes the input and will display everything.  To make sed act more like grep it needs the -n flag, and the p command;  -n means don't display output by default and the p means "print this line"
eg
sed -n '/^ /p'

will display all lines beginning with a space, and similarly
sed -n '/^ ./p'

will display all lines beginning with a space and followed by any other character
EDIT
Base on other comments, it appears your goal is to delete lines beginning with a space, and you want to use sed to do it.
In this case
sed -i '/^ /d'

Basically, "search for lines beginning with a space and delete them"
e.g.
$ cat x
hello
 there
everyone

$ sed -i '/^ /d' x

$ cat x
hello
everyone


Interesting. My goal was actually to get to sed -i but was checking my work first. Should have made that more clear. Could you elaborate on the difference between your solution with the asterisk and $? I don't understand why start of line, space, any characters, end of line is not the same as start of line, space, any characters

^  and ^ .*$ both match the same patterns, but ^  is simpler to understand ("any line beginning with a space" vs "any line beginning with a space and then zero or more other characters until the end of the line").   I've not timed it but I expect it's also faster because we're not forcing the regex to match the whole line, just the first character.   Simplicity is a good thing to aim for (see "KISS principle") because it makes it easier for other people to understand when they (or even older you! "Future you will thank past you") need to fix it :-)

Also, if I understand what you're trying to do (based on other comments), you want to delete lines beginning with a space; I've updated the answer with a sed command that will do that.

If you want to delete all lines that start with one space.
You can use grep with -v :
grep -v -E '^ .*$' Contacts.vcf > tt.txt


-v, --invert-match
Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.

And, $ represents the end of the line.
There should be no characters after it.
Therefore, the asterisk after $ is meaningless.

Thanks. Didn't think to invert it... because yes my goal is to produce a file without those lines. Good call on the last asterisk... doh. I think (hope?) that it was an artifact from trying different multi-line returns until I gave up on that. We just go with that.

I dont get it.?  After you "invert it", what's left is "without those lines"... isn't it?  So, you don't have to learn 2 different tools to reach your goal.

In your original message, you tried to remove these lines that starting with a single space! The "-v" option of grep does exactly doing the same thing.

Note that ^ .*$ matches exactly the same lines that ^  would match, i.e. lines starting with a space.  The added .*$ does nothing as it just says "there may be zero or more characters before the end of the line" (it would be different if it e.g. required at least one other character after the space).  Also, as this is a basic regular expression, you would not need the -E option (which enables extended regular expression parsing).

I was agreeing with you @James! I had not thought to invert, which I found a good way to solve the problem! And then the rest was purely commenting on my lack of succinct code that you pointed out!

@atclaus, If one of the answers here solved your issue, please take a moment and accept it by clicking on the checkmark on the left. That is the best way to express your thanks on the Stack Exchange sites.

You said:

I am trying to find and replace all lines in a text file that start
with a single space and then any characters.

Adding the regexp constructs for the items you listed, that becomes:

I am trying to find and replace all lines in a text file that start
(^) with a single space ( ) and then any characters (technically
..* in a BRE or .+ in an ERE but, since 1 character is "any
characters" when you're just trying to print the whole line that
contains a matching string rather than print the specific matching
string, all you need is . in any regexp flavor).

That'd then be implemented directly as the following using any versions of these tools:
grep '^ .'
sed -n '/^ ./p'
awk '/^ ./'

since:

^ = the start of a string (the current input line in this case).
  = a single space. If you mean any white space character then use [[:space:]] or [[:blank:]] or [ \t] if you just mean blanks or tabs.
. = any character.

The grep command you used was:
grep -E '^ .*$*'

which has these issues:

-E makes grep accept an ERE as the regexp instead of it's default BRE but there's nothing in your regexp that isn't basic regexp syntax so the -E is doing nothing useful.
$ means end of buffer (end of input line in this case) while * is a 0-or-more repetition metachar so $* means "zero or more repetitions of the end of the buffer" - by definition there can't be more than 1 end to the buffer you're working on so that's meaningless and is actually undefined behavior per POSIX.
.* means "zero or more repetitions of any character" but your requirement is for there to be at least 1 character in that position so the * is wrong. You could use .+ in an ERE or ..* in a BRE to mean "one or more" but you don't need "or more" since a single . is adequate to satisfy your requirement that 1 or more characters be present (if there's 1 - good enough).
.* would match NO characters after the space but I assume by "any characters" you mean at least 1 character.

The sed command you used was:
sed 's/^ .*$//g'

which has these issues:

grep and sed both operate on BREs by default, EREs when called with -E. If you thought you needed -E for your grep regexp (you don't) then you should have been calling sed with -E too.
Your grep regexp had a * at the end. Again, if you thought you needed it for grep (you don't) then you should have had it in the sed regexp too.
Just like your grep regexp, the .*$ can just be . unless you really want to allow no characters after the space and then it'd be  .? but  .* would be OK too.
grep is named for g/re/p which are the ed commands to Globally match a Regular Expression and Print the result. Given that, it's clear that grep by default will only print lines that match a regexp. sed is a Stream EDitor so it executes whatever ed commands (and others now) you give it but just like any editor it won't delete anything without you telling it to and so by default it will print every input line. To make sed not do that you need to call it with -n ("by default do not print") and then you need to use a p instruction within the script to tell it to print specific lines.
The g at the end of your sed command is telling sed to match the regexp every time it appears in the input line but you have ^ which can only match once at the start of the line and $ which can only match at the end of the line, either of which is enough to make the regexp only able to match once per line so putting a g at the end of the command telling sed to try to match the regexp many times is doing nothing useful.

Other notes:

Only GNU and BSD variants of sed support -E for EREs, all other sed variants only support BREs.
Regarding "I have tried \s{1}" - \s is shorthand for the POSIX character class [[:space:]] in PCREs, not in POSIX BREs or EREs. GNU sed and GNU grep will accept \s in BREs or EREs, YMMV with non-GNU variants of those or any other tools that operate using BREs and/or EREs rather than PCREs.

